# How can I split data from Slick 3.1(Scala) into 4 parts

Tags: mysql, scala, lucene, slick-3.0

For lucene indexing (v6.1) making fast, I want to split the data from Slick 3.1(Scala) into no of parts(chunks) so as to pass different dataset in threads to speed up the indexing process. I've written following code in Scala to fetch data from MySQL.

```
class NotesService(val databaseService: DatabaseService)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends NoteEntityTable {    
  import databaseService._
  import databaseService.driver.api._
  import com.github.t3hnar.bcrypt._    
  def getNotes(): Future[Seq[NoteEntity]] = db.run(notes.result)    
}
case class NoteEntity(id: Option[Long] = None, title: String, teaser: String, description: String)
```

Code for NotesService

```
class NotesService(val databaseService: DatabaseService)(implicit executionContext: ExecutionContext) extends NoteEntityTable {

  import databaseService._
  import databaseService.driver.api._
  import com.github.t3hnar.bcrypt._

  def getNotes(): Future[Seq[NoteEntity]] = db.run(notes.result)

}
```

To fetch the data from NotesService I've used:

```
def setI = {
    val NUM_THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
    val IndexStoreDir = Paths.get("/var/www/html/Index")
    val analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer()
    val writerConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer)
    writerConfig.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND)
    writerConfig.setRAMBufferSizeMB(500)
      .setMaxBufferedDocs(2)
      .setMergeScheduler(new ConcurrentMergeScheduler())
    val directory = FSDirectory.open(IndexStoreDir)
    var writer = new IndexWriter(directory, writerConfig)

    val threads = Array.ofDim[IndexTh](NUM_THREADS)
    val notes = notesService.getNotes()

    for (i <- 0 until NUM_THREADS){

      threads(i) = new IndexTh(notesService, writer)
      //here on this line I want to pass different sets of data to thread.
    }
    for (i <- 0 until NUM_THREADS) {
      threads(i).start()
      println("Thread " + i + " Started!")
    }
  }
```

Here on line:

```
threads(i) = new IndexTh(notesService, writer)
```

How can I split data from notesService to pass to thread?
How can I split data in notes into multiple chunks?
I want data in this way:

Suppose `notesService.getNotes()` retrieve 20000 rows of data. Now I want to divide the those rows into 5 parts of 4000 rows, so that each 4000 rows of data can be passed to different threads.

Comment: What do you mean by chunks? Pagination?

Comment: I want to pass different sets of data(splitting main data set) in multiple threads

Comment: Uhm I still don't fully understand what the question is. Maybe an example of the output you need would be helpful.

Comment: `notes.map(_.grouped(4))` should work. Doesn't it?

Comment: I've edited the question for better understanding. Can you please review?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the answer researching long time:

Using Thread:

```
def setI = {
    val NUM_THREADS = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors()
    val curNotes = notesService.getNotes()

    val totalRows = Await.result(curNotes, Duration.Inf).length
    var totalPages =  totalRows / NUM_THREADS
    if(totalPages != totalPages.toInt){
      totalPages = totalPages + 1
    }
    var tmp = Await.result(curNotes, Duration.Inf).grouped(totalPages).toList
    val rows = tmp(tmp.length-2) ++ tmp.last
    val threads = Array.ofDim[Index](NUM_THREADS)

    val IndexStoreDir = Paths.get("/var/www/html/LuceneIndex")
    val analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer()
    val writerConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer)
    writerConfig.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND)
    writerConfig.setRAMBufferSizeMB(500)
      .setMaxBufferedDocs(10)
      .setMergeScheduler(new ConcurrentMergeScheduler())
    val directory = FSDirectory.open(IndexStoreDir)
    val writer = new IndexWriter(directory, writerConfig)
    var count = 0

    for(i <- 0 until tmp.length - 2){
      count = i
      threads(i) = new Index(tmp(i), writer, i)
    }
    count = count + 1
    threads(count) = new Index(rows, writer, count)

    for (i <- 0 until NUM_THREADS) {
      println("Thread :" + threads(i).getName + " => " + (i + 1) + " Started!")
      threads(i).start()
    }
  }
```

Using Scala Future:

```
def setFutureIndex = {
    val IndexStoreDir = Paths.get("/var/www/html/LuceneIndex")
    val analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer()
    val writerConfig = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer)
    writerConfig.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE)
    writerConfig.setRAMBufferSizeMB(500)
    val directory = FSDirectory.open(IndexStoreDir)
    val writer = new IndexWriter(directory, writerConfig)
    val notes = notesService.getNotes() //Gets all notes from slick. Data is coming in getNotes()
    var doc = new Document()

    def indexingFuture = {
      val list = Seq (
        notes.map(_.foreach {
          case (note) =>
            writeToDoc(note, writer)
        })
      )
      Future.sequence(list)
    }

    Await.result(indexingFuture, Duration.Inf)

    /*indexingFuture.onComplete {
      case Success(value) => println(value)
      case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace()
    }*/
  }

  def writeToDoc(note: NoteEntity, writer: IndexWriter) = Future {
    println("*****Indexing: " + note.id.get)
    var doc = new Document()
    var field = new TextField("title", " {##" + note.id.get + "##} " + note.title, Field.Store.YES)
    doc.add(field)

    field = new TextField("teaser", note.teaser, Field.Store.YES)
    doc.add(field)

    field = new TextField("description", note.description, Field.Store.YES)
    doc.add(field)

    writer.addDocument(doc)

    writer.commit()
    println("*****Completed: " + note.id.get)
    var status = "*****Completed: " + note.id.get
  }
```